# File Tables in Azure SQLDatabase?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

Is there any way that I can accomplish the functionality of File Tables, in Azure SQL Database?

I know the File Tables functionality is not included in SQL Database Azure, so a way to accomplish these functionality?

I intend to save PDF files, and it can be larger than 20 Mb, and it will be a lot, so I am thinking a way to solve these...

any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

One Azure solution for file storage is Azure Blob Storage.

Azure Blob storage is a service that stores unstructured data in the cloud as objects/blobs. Blob storage can store any type of text or binary data, such as a document, media file, or application installer. Blob storage is also referred to as object storage.

Common uses of Blob storage include:

- Serving images or documents directly to a browser
- Storing files for distributed access
- Streaming video and audio Storing data for backup and restore, disaster recovery, and archiving
- Storing data for analysis by an on-premises or Azure-hosted service

It has RESTful API as well as some SDK for all popular languages that will help you manage your blob files in Azure.

For more details see these pages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/storage/blobs/

Comment: Yes I know the Blob storage functionality, but how would you accomplish the Filetable functionality of Sql Server?, don´t tell me by creating a table that maps to the URL off the blob, I already check that aproach, but doesen't meet the security standard I need,  Filetables are much complex and I need a solution that meet the standard of Filetable in terms of security, I have read that the only way to acomplish is to create a virtual machine on Azure, but before I give up, and create the virtual machine wich is more expensive, I am looking if there is a solution...